# TableView and autolayout, wrong frame for headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm adding a view controller with a table view as a subview of a main view controller. I'm setting the constraints for position and size, i'm not givin a specific frame for the view, but i noticed that the header's labels are in a wrong frame, they have a x position of -30, instead of zero.
This happens only if i use constraints, if i use normal setframe method this problem doesn't happen.
I've tried with layoutIfneeded, or layoutSubviews but nothing seems to work

Comment: Do you use a navigation bar or navigation controller?

Comment: Post what you're calling for setFrame and what your constraints are. My guess is that you have something set wrong for one of your constraints.

Comment: Do you have a custom `headerView`? If so, maybe the constraints there are wrong.